# Importing ArangoDB-Dump in Dockerfile

Tags: linux, docker, arangodb

I wanna build a Docker image based on the official ArangoDB-image. In the Dockerfile, I copy and execute a shell script. This scripts downloads and unzips an Arango dump and imports it with `arangorestore --input-directory "dump"`.

The console log shows, that the import was successfully completed:

```
# Connected to ArangoDB 'http+tcp://127.0.0.1:8529'
# Re-creating document collection 'pages'...
# Loading data into document collection 'pages'...
# Re-creating edge collection 'links_bar'...
# Loading data into edge collection 'links_bar'...
Processed 2 collection(s), read 143363388 byte(s) from datafiles, sent 19 batch(es)
```

However, when I start a container of this image and go to the Arango web interface, it seems like there is no data at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, since ArangoDB's data directory, which is located in `var/lib/arangodb3/databases/database-1/` is declared as a **Volume** in its official Dockerfile, the volume will become empty again after each instruction in my Dockerfile.

A workaround for this problem is either, to overwrite the docker-entrypoint, and initialize the database on runtime (not at build) or, (which is my favorite), simply change ArangoDB's data directory:

```
mkdir /arango-data
chmod 777 /arango-data
sed -i.bak 's/^\(directory = \).*/\1\/arango-data/' /etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf
```

Everything you copy into /arango-data or import in ArangoDB will **not** be deleted, since it's not declared as a volume.